# How to select sys.views of another database from master databse?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, catalog-views

I know I can get views metadata using `sys.views` system catalog view. But now I want to create a centralized function in my `master` database to be called from other databases.

For example, I want to create a procedure, to refresh all views inside a database:

```
select 'execute sp_refreshview ''' + object_name([object_id], db_id()) + ''''
from sys.views
```

I know that I can pass `db_id` to the `object_name` for example, to retrieve data from another database. But how can I tell SQL Server that it should use the `sys.views` of another database?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need nested dynamic SQL to achieve the requirement as stated. If we are sure the database exists, that it's online, and the user has access, we can build a command to execute `sp_executesql` in the specified database, as [Erland Sommarskog describes here](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#dyndbnames), which in turn runs dynamic SQL to generate the list of refresh commands *in that database*:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RefreshAllViewsInDatabase
  @dbname sysname
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @exec nvarchar(750);
  
  SELECT @exec = QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.sp_executesql'
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE state = 0
      AND LOWER(name) = LOWER(@dbname) -- in case case sensitive
      AND HAS_DBACCESS(@dbname) = 1; 

  IF @exec IS NULL
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Database %s is not available.', 11, 1, @dbname);
  END

  DECLARE @outerSQL nvarchar(max) = N'
    DECLARE @innerSQL nvarchar(max) = space(0);
 
    SELECT @innerSQL += N''
    EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule N'' + char(39)    -- single quote
         + QUOTENAME(s.name) + char(46)            -- dot
         + QUOTENAME(v.name) + char(39) + char(59) -- semi-colon
    FROM sys.views AS v 
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
       ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];
 
    PRINT @innerSQL;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @innerSQL;';
 
  EXEC @exec @outerSQL;
END
```

Sample call:

```
EXEC dbo.RefreshAllViewsInDatabase @dbname = N'msdb';
```

For me this yielded something like this (and executed the commands *in msdb*):

```
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule N'[dbo].[syspolicy_policy_category_subscriptions]';
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule N'[dbo].[sysutility_ucp_computer_cpu_health]';
EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule N'[dbo].[sysutility_ucp_mi_volume_space_health]';
...
```

I blogged about this in more detail as the start of a new series:

- ["I want to do X to all the Ys in database Z" – Part 1](https://sqlblog.org/2021/11/08/x-to-y-database-z-1)

Answer (score 2):

To query other databases `sys.views` add the database name before it,

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.views
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks.sys.views
SELECT * FROM WideWorldImporters.sys.views
```

We call it a three-part naming scheme or as in MS DOCS multipart names,
you can refer this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#multipart-names)

So your code becomes like below,

```
select * FROM yourdbname.sys.views
```

To generate all the databases as a dynamic query

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '+convert(varchar(120),DB_NAME(database_id))+'.sys.views' 
  FROM sys.databases
```

Now it's up to you that to create a function or stored procedure according to your need. if your objective is to get all views from all databases and
to do `execute sp_refreshview` then you have to create a dynamic SQL to pull all the data from each database execute it dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

if you selection of view from another server and database so please see below Query

```
select * from [Link Server].[Database Name].[sys].[view]
```